# Получить Exception из BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, многопоточность, backgroundworker

Перерыл интернет и не смог найти ответа на свой вопрос.
Использую backgroundworker, запускаю его в работу таким методом
`async void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)`

Мне нужно выловить ошибку из этого метода в основной поток, для этого дописал

```
bw.RunWorkerCompleted += Bw_RunWorkerCompleted;
private void Bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Произошла ошибка: " + e.Error.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Но ошибка не ловится. Подозреваю, что из-за того, что метод async.

Answer (score 4):

Автор, `async` и `await` призваны как раз исключить необходимость использования `BackgroundWorker`ов и иже с ними. Зачем ты скрещиваешь эти независимые парадигмы? `async` метод порождает фоновую задачу. Исключения в процессе её выполнения сохраняются в контейнер `Task`. Если ты назначаешь продолжение посредством `await`, то оно будут выброшено наверх (или Wait/Result, которые для асинхронных задач использовать строго не рекомендуется). В противном случае - нет. Убери `async` и будет тебе счастье. Если этот метод используют, как `BackgroundWorker`, так и цепочка асинхронных вызовов, сделай два метода - один с модификатором `async`, а другой без него.

Comment: спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Есть ли безусловная необходимость в использовании `Backgroundworker`?

Если необходимо выделить поток для задачи с нагрузкой на CPU можно, например, сделать следующим образом

```
private async Task DoWork()
{
    try
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            DoMyCpuIntensiveWork();
        });
    }
    catch (MyWorkException1 mwex1)
    {
        ShowExceptionMessage(mwex1.ToString());
    }
    catch (MyWorkException2 mwex2)
    {
        ShowExceptionMessage(mwex2.ToString());
    }
}

private void ShowExceptionMessage (string errorMessage)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Произошла ошибка: " + errorMessage);
}
```

Таким образом исключения должны ловиться в вызывающем потоке.

Если вызываемый метод async, то можно и сразу так сделать

```
private async Task DoWork()
{
    try
    {
        await DoMyWorkAsync();
    }
    catch (MyWorkException1 mwex1)
    {
        ShowExceptionMessage(mwex1.ToString());
    }
    catch (MyWorkException2 mwex2)
    {
        ShowExceptionMessage(mwex2.ToString());
    }
}

private void ShowExceptionMessage (string errorMessage)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Произошла ошибка: " + errorMessage);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ